# Creating a multidimensional raster (with time) from many rasters in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, timeslider, space-time-cube

I'm trying to make a time-enabled object from many annual rasters. The eventual goal is to upload them to ArcGIS Online and have them time-enabled with a slider there. I guess I'm confused about the steps to create a time-enabled object like that from many rasters rather than a NetCDF or the like. I created a multiband raster where each band is a year, if that's the correct first step...?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows how to create a multidimensional raster dataset from a collection of images. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFbTFTnsMWM

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/253435)